# PHP wrong date/time

Tags: php, date, time, system

PHP `date()` & `time()` return incorrect time:

When `date.timezone = "Europe/Riga"` the time returned by `date()` was `03-12-2011 08:57:12`, but system time was `03-12-2011 01:57:12` (timezone Europe/Riga - correct time at that moment).
When I changed timezone to "Europe/London", the time changed to `03-12-2011 06:57:12` ( actual time `02-12-2011 23:57:12` )

Time returned by `date` / `hwclock --show` was correct (`03-12-2011 01:57:12` with system timezone set as Riga)

OS:  Debian 6.0

I have checked most of the questions regarding similar issues on SO/Google, but they all seem to have wrong timezone specified.

As far as I can tell there is problem between php -> os. 
Of course, because the incorrect time offset is always constant I could subtract difference, but it is not a proper solution.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for your `date()` value? e.g. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: What happens if you use `DateTime` class to determine the date, in conjunction with `DateTimeZone`? For example `$d = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Riga')); echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem looks similar to what I have seen on one of my servers. Looks to like [bug in php 5.3.2-1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/907816). Try to run the php script in the bug report and post your results.

Comment: Seems that was not an actual bug.  The reporter simply had other code that was resetting the default timezone.  So valid in the sense that you should watch for that.  Beaware of code and .ini settings that can have impact.

Answer (score 23):

Reading PHP manual seems that behaviour of [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is affected by settings in php.ini.
There is another way to set the default timezone in all date/time function and it's the [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). Try to set it with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Riga');
```

instead of your *date.timezone* code.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already tried it without success. The fact that when I changed timezone from Riga to London, time difference was 2 hours suggests that timezone selection "works", but the problem is with the initial time value.

Answer (score 3):

The timezone of the system could be wrong. This results in a shift in a time given by the PHP date() function, althought both php date.timezone (in php.ini) and system time of the server are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem with timezone too. This can be handy for someone.

In my case, Chile Sumer Time CLST returned wrong timzeone offset.

Updating the **timezonedb** worked for me.

Go to: https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

**For Widnows** Download the newest version of dll, copy into "ext" directory. Edit the php.ini and put below line:

extension=php_timezonedb.dll

**For Linux** You can use :

pecl install timezonedb

and in php.ini put:

extension=php_timezonedb.so

Answer (score 1):

This comment for Azerbaijan timezone

I have problem with 'Asia/Baku' on php 7.2 or php 7.1 version.

I solved problem change to 'Europe/Baku'

Answer (score -2):

You have to set date.timezone in php.ini and restart your server
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: This is exactly what the OP meant when he said `date.timezone = "Europe/Riga" `.

Answer (score -4):

PHP time is based on epoch time scale which uses GMT and later UTC. Most people now refer to it as unix time. Because PHP uses unix time, timezones are not used. I believe subtracting the timezone hours in seconds is the correct method to adjust for the differences.

Comment: Unix time is a simple count since a fixed moment in time—it's totally unaffected by time zones. Additionally, PHP has a pretty decent time zone handling; there's absolutely no reason to skip it and write your own.